# How does one slide images smoothly on the iPhone using Lua and the Corona SDK?

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

As I am very new to the lua language I am having a question here.

How can I slide the images forward and backward with in the container smoothly like in Iphone.

Is there any reference or sample code available for that? Also I want to know how can we perform auto scrolling in lua language.

I tried the sample of slides in corona sdk but it is not smooth like iphone.

Thank you,
Monish Calapatapu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily slide images around using the transition commands:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/transitionto

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/transitionfrom

Scrolling is pretty much just a special case of sliding images, where the images happen to be text.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Is there any sample project available for this.

Comment: It's a lot more than just this but here's a sample game framework I made http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/object-oriented-sample-game-framework